# Why TypeError: 'str' object is not callable error has occurred in my code

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am new to learning python, I know this kind questions asked before but i am not able to find any solutions for it. Please check my code and correct me about decorator's functionality, Thank you.

```
def uppercase(func_one):
    func_one = func_one()
    return func_one.upper()

def split(func_two):
    func_two = func_two()
    return func_two.split()

@split

@uppercase    
def CallFunction():
    return "my string was in lower case"

res = CallFunction()
print(res)
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem with your code?

Comment: `func_one()` or `func_two()`. These assume that the variables passed are callable (such as a function or method). You are passing a string to these thus throwing the error.

Comment: Also is there a reason you are using decorators for this?

Comment: @Ralf You check it to run this code in python compiler, I think i can't explain more about it here.

Comment: You could at least attach the full error trace...

Comment: @RanaAalamgeer Users on this site are eager to help, but we would also like to see some effort from your part. Read [ask] and edit your question to include all the necessary parts so that we can better help you

Comment: I will suggest reading [this tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator) (or any else similar) to better understand the concept of decorators

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators are confusing and probably should be avoided till you are super experienced with python. That being said, chaining decorators is even more tricky:

```
from functools import wraps

def split(fn): # fn is the passed in function
    @wraps(fn) # This means we can grabs its args and kwargs
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs): # This is the new function declaration
        return fn(*args, **kwargs).split()
    return wrapped

def uppercase(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs).upper()
    return wrapped

# Order matters. You can't call .upper() on a list
@split
@uppercase 
def CallFunction():
    return "my string was in lower case"

res = CallFunction()
print(res)
```

Alternatively if you don't want the order of these two decorators to matter than you need to handle the `list` case:

```
def uppercase(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(result, list):
            return [x.upper() for x in result]
        return result.upper()
    return wrapped
```

Reference: [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/739654/8150685)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `functools`, you just need to grab the args you are passing.
Here's what you are missing: Add the args being passed inside a wrapper and define that wrapper to accept the args passed. Happy coding!

```
def uppercase(func_one):
    def wrapper(*args):
        x = func_one()
        return x.upper()
    return wrapper

def split(func_two):
    def wrapper(*args):
        y = func_two()
        return y.split()
    return wrapper

@split
@uppercase    
def CallFunction():
    return "my string was in lower case"

res = CallFunction()
print(res)
```