# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable error has occurred - Why?

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, python-decorators

Never heard of decorators.  Was following a Udemy course that referenced this - https://pybit.es/decorators-by-example.html.  Was following the example.  Only trying with one decorator first, but stopped when I got an error.

1. bar outputs correctly
2. bork outputs correctly
3. barf raises an error

Found stackoverflow thread - [Why TypeError: 'str' object is not callable error has occurred in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096886/why-typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-error-has-occurred-in-my-code) - but it does not explain why bork works but barf does not.  Still reading through possible stackoverflow threads for a possible answer.

Using Python 3.8.2, working in IDLE.

```
from functools import wraps

def makebold(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return "<b>" + fn(*args, **kwargs) + "</b>"
    return wrapped()

def hello3():
    foo = "hello world!"
    return foo

@makebold
def hello2():
    foo = "hello world!"
    return foo

print('test hello3\n') #should be 'hello world!'
bar = hello3()
print(bar)
print()
print('test makebold(hello3)\n') #should be '<b>hello world!</b>'
bork = makebold(hello3)
print(bork)
print()
print('test hello2 with decorator\n') #should be '<b>hello world!</b>'
barf = hello2()
print(barf)
```

What have I done wrong?  Why does bork work, but barf raise an error?  How do I correct this to make barf work as well?  Thank you.

Comment: You code behaves the same for any recent python 3 and when run directly with python instead of through IDLE.  Hence tag edits.

Comment: I appreciate it - the original pybit article example referenced a stackoverflow thread from 11 years ago - I'm not sure what version of Python it was written for, hence the tag for python-3.x, however I am using 3.8.2, so I included the tag for python-3.8, because I wasn't sure if which one should be left out.  Thank you for correcting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `makebold` decorator, you are calling the return object which is the incorrect thing to do. You want to return the uncalled object.

```py
def makebold(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return "<b>" + fn(*args, **kwargs) + "</b>"
    return wrapped  # <== HERE
```

When you call it before returning, what ends up happening when you call `hello2()`, `hello2` has already been evaluated to a string so you end up calling a string. By not calling the function on return in your decorator you end up calling the function with `hello2()` instead.